# Mobile app and site show different info for Tags

Tags: bug, tags, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

When viewing my profile in the mobile app it shows different values for my top tags than the website.

For instance, the mobile app show [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) as having 81 votes while the website shows 59 votes.

Not only does it show different vote counts for the tags, there is also a difference in the total number of tags (96 vs 125)

Note: the Stack Overflow app and the Stack Exchange app show the same values, so +1 for consistency :)

**App**:
[image: app tags]

**Website**:
[image: website tags]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)

Comment: Dupe on main meta: [Tag score in app should be for answers only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293404). In short: the app shows score for both Q&A while the web shows score for A only.